# Make can't find libusb-1.0 when compiling lm4flash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libusb

I'm trying to get a Tiva Launchpad EK-TM4C1294XL working with my laptop which is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I've been following [this guide](http://chrisrm.com/howto-develop-on-the-ti-tiva-launchpad-using-linux/), but I'm stuck on step 9. When I run the `make` command, I get the following error:

```
Package libusb-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libusb-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libusb-1.0' found
cc -Wall  lm4flash.c  -o lm4flash
lm4flash.c:30:20: fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'lm4flash' failed
make: *** [lm4flash] Error 1
```

The closest post I've found with a similar `libusb` error was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613962/cmake-make-cannot-find-libusb) but I'm not using `cmake` so the solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: I suspect that it doesn’t make any difference  whether you’re using ``make`` or ``cmake``.

Comment: I only mention it because the other question I linked gave a solution that involved changing a file in a directory called `cmake_modules` which I don't have